# How to Handle props history location search parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a website, made with React, in where I have different components, one of which is the NavBar with a Search field.

```
class SearchBar extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        query:''
    }
}

changeHandler = (e)=>{
    this.setState(
        {query: e.target.value}
    )
}

enterHandler = (e)=>{
    if(e.key ==='Enter'){
        var q = `?q=${(this.state.query).trim().replace(new RegExp(' ','gi'),'%20')}`
        if(this.props.history.location.pathname === '/search'){
            this.props.history.location.search = q
        }else{
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: '/search',
            search: q
        })
    }
        
    }
}

render(){
    return (
        <TextField placeholder="Search" InputProps={{
            startAdornment:(
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <SearchIcon/>
                </InputAdornment>
            )
        }}
        required
        value={this.state.query}
        onChange={this.changeHandler}
        onKeyPress={this.enterHandler}
        ></TextField>
    )
}
```

}

and a Search Component where I fetch the query to the database and back on

```
class Search extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        posts:{}
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch(`/searchpost${this.props.location.search}`).then(res=> res.json()).then(searchs => this.setState({posts:searchs},()=>{
        console.log('Fetched ...',searchs)
    })).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err.message)
    })
}


render(){

    return <div>hemlo</div>
}
```

}

The thing is this works perfectly if im in another route, i.e Home, etc.
But if im in the Search component already, and I use the search field in that route, it doesn't bring anything up. Is there any way that when I change location.search to the new query the sites updates and fetches the new query? . I'm sorry, I don't know explicitly about routing or React per se. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should push to the history the new search data, not just assign it to the props object.  In other words remove the if statement that handles the search in a special way.

Comment: If you want the Search route to not be in the history stack multiple times, use replace instead of push.

Comment: Thanks Jacob!, I'll try to refactor this along those guidelines. In any case, is there any documentation where I can read about the history stack and how it works precisely?. I've googled it but the info is either too scarce or not truly what I've searched for

Comment: There are doc links on the history [github page](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history).

Comment: Class components do not rerender unless they detect a change in their props (this is a shallow compare, i.e. references and primitives on the first level). When you directly change `this.props.history.location.search = q` React has no idea that history has changed. When you change it through history.push or history.replace etc React Router is listening to these changes and handles updating the props.